# How to compare NSNumber with a decimal value?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsnumber, ocunit

I recently upgraded from iOS 5 to iOS 6 and found this unit test was failing

```
- (void)testCalculatesDistanceBetweenTwoPoints
{
    self.sut = [[DistanceCalculator alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D start = {.latitude = 34.32, .longitude = 99.13};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D finish = {.latitude = 105.94, .longitude = 27.73};
    NSNumber *distance = [self.sut kilometresBetweenPlace1:start andPlace2:finish];
    NSNumber *expected = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3822.23073702318];
    STAssertEqualObjects(distance, expected, @"");
}
```

The failing asserting

> '3822.23073702318' should be equal to '3822.23073702318'

When I print the raw value of each number I get what looks like the same value

```
2012-10-23 20:01:42.970 HelloWorld[1573:c07] 1 3822.23073702318
2012-10-23 20:01:42.970 HelloWorld[1573:c07] 2 3822.23073702318
```

When I print the type of each number I get what looks like the same (could I be doing this wrong?)

```
2012-10-23 20:06:37.309 HelloWorld[1611:c07] 1 __NSCFNumber 
2012-10-23 20:06:37.309 HelloWorld[1611:c07] 2 __NSCFNumber
```

Here is the full blown implementation if that helps

```
- (NSNumber *)kilometresBetweenPlace1:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)place1 andPlace2:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)place2
{
    MKMapPoint start = MKMapPointForCoordinate(place1);
    MKMapPoint finish = MKMapPointForCoordinate(place2);

    double distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(start, finish) / 1600;

    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance];
}
```

Comment: checking non-intger for equality is always risky, due to rounding errors. you should check, that the value are within a certain range.

Comment: I did see an ocunit method "STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy" -anyone use this with success?

Comment: @CodaFi why the float value instead of the double? won't that cut out a ton of the accuracy ?

Comment: Perhaps I mistyped.  You are correct.

Comment: btw: your `kilometresBetweenPlace1: andPlace2:` returns miles, not kilometre, as you are dividing the meters by 1600.

Comment: ... and there are 1609.34 metres in a mile, not 1600.

Comment: @vikingosegundo great question -is there a function in the base SDK that does this already?

Comment: What do you want: kilometres or miles?

Comment: @vikingosegundo miles would be the preferred (using this in a google places like app to show x miles away from current location)

Comment: You should display km or mi in respect to users locale, as in most parts of the world the metric system is used. To calculate miles, just rename ur method and divide by 1609.34

Comment: @vikingosegundo I would but this app is only available in the US (so for now I left out the locale work you mentioned)

Comment: even if you make a us-only app people might want to switch to another locale, as they are used to metric system. not only people born in the US live in the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might follow this discussion -here is what I ended up with

```
- (void)testCalculatesDistanceBetweenTwoPoints
{
    double accuracy = 0.00000000001;
    self.sut = [[DistanceCalculator alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D start = {.latitude = 34.32, .longitude = 99.13};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D finish = {.latitude = 105.94, .longitude = 27.73};
    NSNumber *distance = [self.sut kilometresBetweenPlace1:start andPlace2:finish];
    NSNumber *expected = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3822.23073702318];
    STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy([distance doubleValue], [expected doubleValue], accuracy, @"");
}
```